# How to expand Raid 5 on ICH10 - Gigabyte ex58-ds4?

Tags: raid, raid-5

I was wondering if there is a relatively simple way to expand my HD space.

My setup is 4 x 640 GB drives. Motherboard has 4 ports on 1 controller and 2 ports on another controller, however they can't be joined.

I would like to somehow get more store space in raid configuration. One scenario that I can see working is replacing one 640 drive for a 2 TB drive. Waiting for raid to rebuild. Rinse and repeat. However, I have no idea if I would be able to even see/access the new space.

Comment: I am really not looking forward to rebuilding my RAID, nor do I have the space to backup 2TB. Also, today it's 2 TB, tomorrow it'll be 10, eventually I wont be able to effectively backup the raid.

Someone mentioned that theoretically the Hard Drive controller will  see the 2TB drive, but existing Raid will only allocate 640 GB on the new drive. Once all 4 drives are in place, I might have the other 1.3 TB available to create 2nd Raid array. This is purely a theory, but it seems possible.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Backup all data, install four new drives and then restore data.  Adding one 2TB drive will unlikley report more than 640GB in the array.

A rebuild is likley your fastest solution even if it means a reinstall of OS and a restore of data.

Comment: +1 here. Just backup all the data, break the array and create a new one using new drives of like sizes. I think even if you replace each drive in turn with 2TB drives your array will remain the same size. You are better off creating a new array.